# backbone view - is not defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This really confuses me, I think I'm stupid but I've searched and have done whatever I could. 
Whenever I declare a view and run BDD test with jasmine, it always returns "undefined is not a function". This is code

```
window.LocationView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // create new marker first
        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            title: this.model.get('name'),
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.model.get('lat'), this.model.get('long')), // give the position here
        });

        // bind events
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.marker.setTitle(this.model.get("name"));
        this.marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(this.model.get('lat'), this.model.get('long')));
    },
});
```

This is how I declared it :

```
this.view = new LocationView({model: this.location});
this.view = new LocationView();
// neither of these ones work.
```

This is the error when I run this code with jasmine:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at [object Object].make (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.5.3/backbone-min.js:29:37)
    at [object Object]._ensureElement (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.5.3/backbone-min.js:30:270)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.5.3/backbone-min.js:28:127)
    at new <anonymous> (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.5.3/backbone-min.js:32:136)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (http://localhost/gmap_api/public/test/spec/specs.js:62:21)
    at [object Object].execute (http://localhost/gmap_api/public/test/spec/jasmine/jasmine.js:1001:15)
    at [object Object].next_ (http://localhost/gmap_api/public/test/spec/jasmine/jasmine.js:1790:31)
    at [object Object].start (http://localhost/gmap_api/public/test/spec/jasmine/jasmine.js:1743:8)
    at [object Object].execute (http://localhost/gmap_api/public/test/spec/jasmine/jasmine.js:2070:14)
    at [object Object].next_ (http://localhost/gmap_api/public/test/spec/jasmine/jasmine.js:1790:31)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "declare a view and then declare a new view" means. Are you instantiating one LocationView and then a second LocationView? The first one is fine but the second one isn't? Or does `new LocationView({model: this.location})` work but `new LocationView();` doesn't?

Comment: @muistooshort: Sorry for bad English, I fix it. It means it prompts me LocationView is not defined everytime, although I declared it ??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I included my javascript files in the wrong order. Import them like so:

```
jQuery.js 
Underscore.js
Backbone.js
YourCode.js
```

If that's not the case then post the line at which this exception occurs.

Comment: This doesn't resolve my problem. I recreate my project using jasmine at the moment. But this looks like the best answer here. Thanks

Comment: You should include the development version of Backbone and see exactly where in the make function you get the error, when Backbone tries to create a HTML element for your view. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-117 It looks like you don't have $ available when you are running the tests

Comment: I was confused by this answer initially. To clarify, if you're running Jasmine under Ruby/Rails, "Import them like so:" means, "add them explicitly by name in this order to the 'src_files:" section of your jasmine.yml."  By default, jasmine.yml just has "public/javascripts/**/*.js" so you want to add "public/javascripts/jquery-x.y.z.js", etc to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the View's definition is before the initialization code? If it's in a separate file, are you sure the View's definition is executed first?

Comment: when I declare new Model's definition and call it. It works fine :(