# Jasmine won't allow attaching fixture to the DOM before spec starts to execute

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, jasmine, handlebars.js

In my Backbone view in Rails 4, I'm attempting to have Handlebars compile a template.  It needs to be available in the DOM before it can be compiled.

```
var ItemsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template:  Handlebars.compile($("[data-name=items]").html()), 
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({ items: this.collection.toJSON() }));
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.$el = $("#items");
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "change", this.render);
  }
});
```

When I run this in the browser, Handlebars compiles fine, but when I run my Jasmine spec on this--providing it with a fixture--the fixture gets loaded AFTER the Backbone View starts to execute and thus I get, `Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined`--no script tag (in this case) is available to be compiled.

It was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736727/testing-backbone-views-with-jasmine) that the template should be made into a function so that it could be invoked later, after the DOM is loaded, but I'm not sure if that is the best thing to do b/c I have to change my code to "make Jasmine work" even though the functionality works fine with the browser.  I did actually try that out (& `loadFixtures` worked fine), but in subsequent tests, I run into the same problem--namely,...

...needing to attached the HTML fixture to the DOM BEFORE the `template`'s Handlebars compilation process needs to begin--before the spec starts to run on the Backbone View.

Here is my spec for this...

```
describe('Items View', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    loadFixtures('index');
    this.view = new ItemsView({
      collection: items_scaffold // provided above
    });
  });

  it("should have Handlebars template compiled", function() {
    expect(this.view.template).toBeDefined();
  });

});
```

I'm using `jasmine-jquery.js`.  On my Rails layout HTML file, I've placed `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` at the bottom of the body, so I'm guessing it's not a "document ready" issue.

I've gone through the answers to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715207/how-can-i-get-my-jasmine-tests-fixtures-to-load-before-the-javascript-considers), but I can't seem to get them to work in my case.  Is there a plug-in that would enable attaching the fixture to the DOM before the jasmine spec begins to run--before `beforeEach`--or maybe a method in `jasmine-jquery.js` that I've missed?

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not a Jasmine issue but actually it has to do with the way you coded your View.

The problem is that your jQuery selector for the Handlebars compilation is being evaluated at DECLARATION TIME versus INSTANTIATION TIME which is what you are expecting:

```
var ItemsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: Handlebars.compile($("[data-name=items]").html()), 
  ...
```

Here you are calling `Handlebars.comple` and also the jQuery selector `$("[data-name=items]")` on the moment this code declaration is being parsed by the browser. Which is way before your instantiation `this.view = new ItemsView({ ... });`

In order to only run this when you do `new` then you would need to put the Handlebars compilation step inside your initialize method:

```
var ItemsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.template = Handlebars.compile($("[data-name=items]").html()), 
    this.$el = $("#items");
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "change", this.render);
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({ items: this.collection.toJSON() }));
  }
});
```

Please give it a try this way.

Comment: If you dont want to parse the jQuery selector every time, I would suggest you not even storing the template in the DOM but instead in an external HBS file. Then you can put it back to where it was before.

Comment: It's looking like this might be a Rails 4 problem as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394914/jasmine-wont-load-javascript-files-from-asset-pipeline .

Comment: After making your changes, I still get the error, `You passed undefined`. I have Teaspoon w/ Jasmine 2.0. A comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943449/backbone-view-is-not-defined said I need to change my `src_files` in `jasmine.yml`, but it looks like I'm not even READING jasmine.yml! I'll have to research this... reading through this... https://github.com/travisjeffery/jasmine-jquery-rails/issues/4 .  I'd upvote you, but not qualified just yet!

Comment: Regarding the external HBS file, how would I access that for the ItemsView's file. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry that my suggestion didn't work. Regarding external HBS file, it depends on how you are doing you overall module strategy. 

If you use RequireJS/AMD you can just require it using text! plugin. I believe in Rails there is also a way to include files using JST, please have look here: http://jacopretorius.net/2013/11/integrating-ejs-templates-into-rails.html

Comment: Your suggestion of the external HBS file solved it for me!  Using the ruby gem (plug-in) `handlebars_assets`, I made a JST in my Rails asset pipeline, enabling me to access the template directly from my javascripts.  No need for `loadFixtures` here.  I changed `Handlebars.compile($("[data-name=items]").html())` to `HandlebarsTemplates['items/index']`. The `HandlebarsTemplates` object is provided by the gem (but need `//= require_tree ./templates` at the very top of `app.js` to get that object--&, of course, the `.hbs` template(s) in the `templates` folder). Thanks so much! Big problem solved!

Comment: Glad to hear, Matt! :)

Comment: Oh, and one addendum,.. I had to use the `magic_lamp` gem (`MagicLamp.load("rails_controller_name/index");` in the spec) to enable loading loading the actual page for the testing (in addition to the Handlebars template)...I guess I could have used a `loadFixtures` for that, but `magic_lamp` prevents code duplication.